# Different PHP SoapClient parsing if result has one or multiple items

Tags: php, arrays, soap, foreach

I'm consuming a WebService with PHP and (for testing purposes) SoapUI.

I've already tried this option, but no luck:

```
'feature'  => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
```

The PHP call:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall($request->operation, array($params));
```

From my provider, the XML response are:

1) Many results:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <C_FOO_LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <C_FOO>
        <NAME>Victor</NAME>
        <SURNAME>Marconi</SURNAME>
     </C_FOO>
     <C_FOO>
        <NAME>Ayrton</NAME>
        <SURNAME>Senna</SURNAME>
     </C_FOO>
     (...)
  </C_FOO_LIST>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

2) One result:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <C_FOO_LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <C_FOO>
        <NAME>Victor</NAME>
        <SURNAME>Marconi</SURNAME>
     </C_FOO>
  </C_FOO_LIST>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Which seems to me, pretty consistent.

But, PHP seems to process them differently:

1)

```
array (
  'C_FOO' => 
   array (
     0 => 
     array (
       'NAME' => 'Victor',
       'SURNAME' => 'Marconi')
     )
     1 => 
     array (
      'NAME' => 'Ayrton',
      'SURNAME' => 'Senna')
     )
)
```

2)

```
array (
  'C_FOO' => 
   array (
     'NAME' => 'Victor',
     'SURNAME' => 'Marconi')
   )
)
```

The fact that PHP isn't creating a numbered array for the last response (single item) implies that I can't treat all cases with a simple foreach.

How can I force PHP to always return a numbered array? (even if the result is a single item)

```
array (
  'C_FOO' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
     'NAME' => 'Victor',
     'SURNAME' => 'Marconi')
    )
)
```

Comment: You mention SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS isn't working.  Just to confirm, are you using it like this: $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('features' =>
SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));  You were missing an 's'

Comment: @KrisPeeling I was facing similar problem, this helped